# ApiException: 17: Error resolution was canceled by the user, original error message: INTERNAL_ERROR: null

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

Got a released app which is using the Google DriveApi (not REST) and it has been working fine for many years.

Started development on next release where I want to use REST. During development I wanted the app to use both APIs. (Eventually I will probably stop using the DriveApi and only use REST.) Implemented first feature using REST. Works fine listing some Google Drive folders using my main Google account.

However, some serious problem occur when I try to use the original DriveApi (not REST): com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 17: Error resolution was canceled by the user, original error message: INTERNAL_ERROR: null

There's no problem to log-in, but the problem occurs e.g. for a simple function getting the Goggle Drive root folder, and I use the proper scope for non-REST: Drive.SCOPE_FILE

If I re-install the released version from app-store (which does not use REST and never has), I get the same problem! I have a couple of devices which have the app-store version (not re-installed), and the app work fine on these using my main Google account!

Then I created a new Google account, and everything works fine when using this account. I can re-install from app-store and all works just fine.

So the problem occurs when I re-install the app and use my main Google account. Seems like my main Google account somehow got corrupted when I was using REST. But not for the devices where I have not re-installed the app!

I can see these in log just before my app gets exception, but I can see similar logs when all works fine:
2018-11-10 07:56:11.381 1152-1792/? W/AppOps: Bad call: specified package com.google.android.gms under uid 10190 but it is really 10020

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Strange...

After using REST successfully, and getting the ApiException: 17: Error resolution was canceled by the user, original error message: INTERNAL_ERROR: null
when using the Drive API (not REST), do this:

Open https://myaccount.google.com/
Remove the app's access to your account.
Uninstall the app on your device.
Re-install the app on your device.

When you then use the Drive API (not REST) it works fine!.

Try the Drive REST API and you get:
ApiException: 17: Error resolution was canceled by the user, original error message: INTERNAL_ERROR: null

One can note that the old (more or less deprecated) API GoogleApiClient works fina all the time...

Hmm...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this will help, but for me, I was getting this error with an Android app + the Awareness APIs. I realized I needed [an API Key](https://developers.google.com/awareness/android-api/get-a-key) for the Awareness API features (Snapshot and Fence) to work. After I added that, the error went away.

I assume some of the other Google APIs may need that as well in your manifest.

Note: The link is for the awareness API, you would need to check the API guide for other specific APIs.